# Google map api and laravel to display gpx file on a map

Tags: php, laravel

is out there any library or directly a google Map API that allows to load a gpx file and display it on a map, using Php?

Comment: i did find one using javascript not php, if you're interested in that

Comment: @chris94 yes thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a javascript gpx file viewer [gpxviewer](https://github.com/peplin/gpxviewer)